# innerHTML not working inside a for loop

Tags: innerhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Find sunday on jan ist </title>
</head>
<!-- body containing submit button to check and div to display the result-->
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="findSun()" />
<div id="output1">

</div>
</body>
<script>
function findSun()
{
//for loop that checks january 1st on each year from 2015 to 2015 for sunday
for(var year = 2015; year <= 2030; year++)
  {

    var today = new Date(year,0,1);
    var dd = today.getDay();
    if(dd===0)
    {
        var dis = "Jan 1st Of :" + year + "is Sunday";
        console.log(dis);
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = dis;
    }

    else
    {
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML= "";

    }
  }

}
</script>
</html>
```

it is a simple program which checks for sunday on jan 1st for each year starting from 2015-30.I am able to get the correct output on console,but I am not able to get correct output on page using innerHTML. I am new to javascript any help is apprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are erasing the content of your 'output1 element' each time the day don't match.

If you want to keep the previously found sunday, you can just append -with += - to the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Find sunday on jan ist </title>
</head>
<!-- body containing submit button to check and div to display the result-->
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="findSun()" />
<div id="output1">

</div>
</body>
<script>
function findSun()
{
//for loop that checks january 1st on each year from 2015 to 2015 for sunday
for(var year = 2015; year <= 2030; year++)
  {

    var today = new Date(year,0,1);
    var dd = today.getDay();
    if(dd===0)
    {
        var dis = "Jan 1st Of :" + year + "is Sunday";
        console.log(dis);
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += ", " + dis;                                                                                                                                                
    }

    else
    {
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += "\n";

    }
  }

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems, the first one is noted above with your else statement erasing the contents of the  that can be fixed with a +=.

The second issue is that your if statement has one too many "="

```
<title>Find sunday on jan ist </title>
</head>
<!-- body containing submit button to check and div to display the result-->
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="findSun()" />
<div id="output1">

</div>
</body>
<script>
function findSun()
{
//for loop that checks january 1st on each year from 2015 to 2015 for sunday
for(var year = 2015; year <= 2030; year++)
  {

    var today = new Date(year,0,1);
    var dd = today.getDay();
    if(dd==0)
    {
        var dis = "Jan 1st of: " + year + " is Sunday";
        console.log(dis);
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += dis + "<br>";                                                                                                                                                
    }

  }

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this It will do the job
Problem was you were over writing the innerhtml not appending thats why it was creating problems.

```
for(var year = 2015; year <= 2030; year++)
 {

var today = new Date(year,0,1);
var dd = today.getDay();
if(dd===0)
{
    var dis = "Jan 1st Of :" + year + "is Sunday";
    console.log(dis);
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += dis + "</br>";
}

else
{
document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += "";

}
}
```